# How can I allow all users to run mount as root?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, mount, pam

How can I allow all users to run `mount` as root? I know there's a lot of solutions out there recommending the following edit, but it's not working for me.

I've edited `/etc/sudoers` to include:

```
ALL     ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/mount
ALL     ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/mount.cifs
```

If I try to mount a drive as a non-root user using just `mount -t cifs`(...) I get "only root can do that". If I prefix this with `sudo`, it mounts as desired without issue. The problem is that I need this command to run in a `pam` login script and I don't think using `sudo` will work. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're configuring sudo, it's quite natural that it only affects what you can do with sudo.

I see no reason why it shouldn't be possible to make pam use sudo.

If it's only a static set of devices, you can define them in `/etc/fstab`, if you just add the `user` option, any user can mount them.

If you really want users to be able to mount anything (but beware what that encompasses) just running `mount`, make `mount` setuid. (I won't give the command to do that, as it's dangerous and I'm hoping requiring you to search for it, makes you think once more).

Comment: I read `messages` wrong-- when using `sudo mount` in the `pam_script_ses_open` script after editing `/etc/sudoers`, the error is a cifs auth error, not a perms error running mount. Running this with a test user and manually specifying the creds mounts as expected. So this is an issue of pam passing authentication variables. Thanks, and apologies-- you confirmed an incorrect assumption of mine that solved this step.